# Undefined variable: row on CodeIgniter when trying to access single row

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a database of pets, and basically I want to view a pet's details by its ID. Here is what my Controller method is like:

```
public function details()
{
    $this->load->model('animalsmodel');
    $row = $this->animalsmodel->details($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('animals/details', $row);
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');
}
```

And here is the `AnimalsModel` code for grabbing the relevant row:

```
function details($animalId) {
    $q = $this->db->query('SELECT Animals.Name, Animals.DateAdmitted, Animals.FoundDescription, Animals.Description, Animals.Neutered, Animals.DateNeutered, Types.Name AS Type, Healthchecks.CheckInfo FROM Animals LEFT JOIN Types ON Animals.TypeId = Types.TypeId LEFT JOIN Healthchecks ON Animals.HealthcheckId = Healthchecks.HealthcheckId WHERE Animals.AnimalId = ?', $animalId);
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $q->row();
        return $row;
    } else
    {
        echo "No Results Man!!";
    }
}
```

I have run that MySQL query manually in phpMyAdmin, and it works, it gets me the correct row.

***EDIT:*** I have just gone ahead and did a `var_dump()` on the $row object, and I got the following:

```
object(stdClass)#17 (8) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "Quemby" ["DateAdmitted"]=> string(10) "2013-01-28" ["FoundDescription"]=> string(94) "The story of how I got to be here. Phasellus ornare. Fusce mollis. Duis sit amet diam eu dolor" ["Description"]=> string(65) "massa non ante bibendum ullamcorper. Duis cursus, diam at pretium" ["Neutered"]=> string(1) "0" ["DateNeutered"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["Type"]=> string(3) "Dog" ["CheckInfo"]=> string(26) "a, facilisis non, bibendum" }
```

So it looks like I have my row! but why does CI keeps complaining about `Undefined variable: row` :(

Comment: please print $row and check is it correct or not?

Comment: First Print: $q->num_rows();
Check if  greater than 0?

Comment: @Praveen and Veekay: Q Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

```
public function details()
{
    $this->load->model('animalsmodel');
    $row = $this->animalsmodel->details($this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['row'] = $row;
    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('animals/details', $data);
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');
}
```

Now try to access data in view.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks very much Praveen ^_^. Can you please explain why this worked and mine didn't? Is it a convention in CI that the thing being passed must always be called $data and be of type array?

Comment: Read this you will get idea. still you have doubt leave a message for me i will get back to you.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check your last query in CI by using

```
    <pre> <?php print_r($this->db->last_query()) ?> </pre>
```

then copy past it and try it in phpMyadmin or whatever you use.

and for better result/review/maintain your MODEL code should be look like this

```
  function details($animalId) {
$this->db->select('Animals.Name, Animals.DateAdmitted, Animals.FoundDescription,...');
$this->db->where('AnimalId', $animalId);
$this->db->join('Types'       , 'Types.TypeId               = Animals.TypeId'       , 'left');
$this->db->join('Healthchecks', 'Healthchecks.HealthcheckId = Animals.HealthcheckId', 'left');
$this->db->from('Animals');
$q = $this->db->get();

if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $row = $q->row();
    return $row;
} else
{
    echo "No Results Man!!";
}
```

}

and last thing is:
in CI it is better to use names like follow:
   mymodelname_model not myModelNameModel
in your case
   animals_model not animalsmodel

thats the way CI users do it :)

Enjoy your code